# How to send login credentials to remote website?

Tags: authentication, httpwebrequest, powershell-3.0

I am running PowerShell v3 and I would like to use PowerShell to login to a remote website that requires a user login and password. I have searched Google and I cannot find how to do this. I did try the following bit of code but it didn't work:

```psh
$HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($uri)
$creds = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential $global:USERNAME, $global:USERPASS
$newURI = new-object System.Uri $uri
$credcache = new-object System.Net.CredentialCache
$credcache.Add($newURI, "Basic", $creds)
$HTTP_Request.Credentials = $credcache
$HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
$HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Additional Info**

I noticed some very strange behaviour in the responses I have received. PowerShell will return an error saying that the site is returning '401 unauthorized.' However, if I visit the site manually in a browser, I receive a 404. Why don't these return codes match up?

On another link, PowerShell returns 'Too many automatic redirections were attempted.' Again visiting with a browser returns a login page. Even increasing the max number of allowed redirections, results in the same message being returned by PowerShell. I am beginning to think PowerShell is broken.

Comment: The answer to your question depends on how and where you want to log in (if I'm not mistaken the `Credentials` property is for HTTP authentication, so it won't help you with a web application login). Not much we could tell you from seeing just your code.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yes this is for HTTP authentication, not for a web application login.

Comment: What is the server response? Do you get an error? Do you have access to the server logs? They usually are more informative than client-side messages.